# C# dotnet app deployed on kubernetes performance diagnostic using dotnet trace and counters

Tags: docker, kubernetes, .net-core, profiling, trace

I am trying to enable performance diagnostics for an application deployed on a kubernetes(GKE) cluster using dotnet-trace and dotnet counters. For doing this I am adding a performance diagnostic sidecar with my application container.
diagnostics.Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-alpine AS tools
RUN dotnet tool install --tool-path /tools dotnet-trace
RUN dotnet tool install --tool-path /tools dotnet-counters
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-alpine AS runtime
COPY --from=tools /tools /tools
ENV PATH="/tools:${PATH}"
ENV COMPlus_EnableDiagnostics="0"
WORKDIR /tools
```

The app that I am using here is a simple hello world app.
This is how I am deploying these containers on GKE:
deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: demo-dotnet-diagnostics
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demo-diagnostics
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: demo-diagnostics
    spec:
      shareProcessNamespace: true
      containers:
      - name: demo-app
        image: gcr.io/qp-fda-mystudies-2020-07/dotnetapp:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        volumeMounts:
        - name: dotnet-diagnostics
          mountPath: /tmp
      - name: demo-diagnostics
        image: gcr.io/qp-fda-mystudies-2020-07/diagnostics:latest
        stdin: true
        tty: true
        command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
        args: ["dotnet-trace collect -p 1; dotnet-counters monitor -p 1"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: dotnet-diagnostics
          mountPath: /tmp
      volumes:
      - name: dotnet-diagnostics
        emptyDir: {}
```

The problem I am facing here is the diagnostics container keeps on running into crashloopbackoff. The error I am getting here is: Failed to start the counter session: Microsoft.Diagnostics.NETCore.Client.ServerNotAvailableException: Process 1 not running compatible .NET runtime.
I have been following these articles and threads:
https://github.com/dotnet/diagnostics/issues/810 and https://im5tu.io/article/2020/01/diagnostics-in-.net-core-3-using-dotnet-counters-with-docker/
The goal is to run these diagnostics processes in the background and to push the information captured using these tools to stackdriver.
I don't know what I am missing here, since I am relatively new to dotnet. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Note tested but I would try to remove this line (or setting it to 1):

```
ENV COMPlus_EnableDiagnostics="0"
```

[Source from MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/debugging-profiling#enable-diagnostics)